# Can i be two places at once in python cycle

Tags: python, scripting, python-3.x

I'm doing this in python, in case that changes anything.

I'm trying to make a lamp/bit go 1-0-1-0 until the user says "okay"
the "okay" should indicate that the user has found the lamp/Bit IRL.

Now i'm struggling to find a way to ask the user a question, (because it stops the program cycle), when I also want the lamp bit to go On/Off on repeat, while waiting for the user to write yes or click yes

Atm i'm looking at this idea

```
def click(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0)


newLampsadded = int(input( " How many new lamps : " ))
lamps = newLampsadded - 1

for lamp in range(lamps):
    while feedback is not "y":
        Click(x, y)              #On
        Click(x+50, y+10)        #Off
        feedback = input("have you found the lamp y/n") #Is the lamp found
```

anyway i can get a feedback that doesnt stop the cycle of turning the lamp On/Off

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not immediately familiar with the Win32API, but you're going to need to multi-thread this application. Because the for loop for the click needs to happen at the same time as your input (which is a **blocking** call) it needs to happen on a different thread.